# Parsing JSON in rxjs ajax callback not working

Tags: json, angular, parsing, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to parse a JSON string in a ajax callback in Angular2.
After I call `response.json())` and do a `console.log()` it works fine.

This is the JSON I am trying to parse:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "id": "14cf4717-f5b6-4002-96b2-321324fc4077",
    "number": "1234",
    "sections": [
      {
        "id": "53f43dd7-4c93-4925-a51d-c6f81f314275",
        "description": "Test",
        "created_at": "2017-10-07 15:08:01",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-07 15:08:01",
        "lines": [
          {
            "id": "73fab07f-4401-43a4-99a4-13c891907ea7",
            "product_id": "62aa5388-712d-4ab1-9e64-6849889194d1",
            "product_name": "Product",
            "product_description": "test",
            "product_type": "product",
            "quantity": "1.00",
            "product": {
              "id": "62aa5388-712d-4ab1-9e64-6849889194d1",
              "name": "Product",
              "description": "test"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "notes": []
  }
}
```

In this function:

```
 public getQuotation(quotationId: string, callback: Function) {
    this.http.get('/quotation/' + quotationId).subscribe((response) => {

      const responseJson = response.json();
      console.log(responseJson);

      callback(null);
    }, () => {
      callback(null);
    });
  }
```

Result is like expected:
[image: parsed json]

But when I add this line **below** the `console.log()`: 
`const quotation = <FinBaseModel>(responseJson.data);`

```
public getQuotation(quotationId: string, callback: Function) {
    this.http.get('/quotation/' + quotationId).subscribe((response) => {

      const responseJson = response.json();
      console.log(responseJson);

       const quotation = <FinBaseModel>(responseJson.data);

      callback(quotation);
    }, () => {
      callback(null);
    });
  }
```

Then the `lines` array is empty...

[image: Missing lines array]

I don't understand how that is possible because I do the `console.log()` before I try to cast it to a `FinBaseModel`

Does anyone know how this is possible and how I can fix it?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Guessing you're parsing it in a callback to some AJAX request?

Comment: @llama yes, i updated my post

Comment: Please show a printed debugger version of the string or the actual string as it appears before you try to parse it. This json, if stringified, will parse without problems.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using JSON.parse you can do this way:

```
this.http.get('/quotation/' + quotationId)
    .map(response=> response.json())
    .subscribe((responseData) => {
         console.log(responseData);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

console.log prints the object by reference. it was mutated by the time the printing happens, probably by the callback.

```
console.log(responseJson.data) 
const quotation = <FinBaseModel>(responseJson.data);
callback(quotation);
```

Comment: You are right! I was looking at the wrong place.. I am binding the object to another component in the HTML and in that component the object got mutated.

Answer (score 0):

width the information you have provided for now I can't help you with the solution. But I can help you to debug your code properly:
to see the actual values and if the value is changed at the time you're logging it you have to log its clone to be sure that callbacks won't change it. So change your `console.log(response.data)` with `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)))`. Change both logs and compare results. I think this will help you to understand that it's not changed right there but any of your callbacks are changing it. Because TypeScript types don't do anything actually but just providing you type insurance and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpClient.
[Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http) 
This should do:

```
http.get<ItemsResponse>('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
// data is now an instance of type ItemsResponse, so you can do this:
   this.results = data.results;
});
```

```
 getQuotation(quotationId: string, callback: Function) {
    this.http.get<FinBaseModel>('/quotation/' + quotationId).subscribe((data) => {

 // call your callback here and pass 'data'
 // callback(data)
 // or return the value and consume it no need to json to
    return data
}
```